# Rails phantom content flashing when going back and forth in Safari on iOS devices

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, debugging, safari

I was making a Ruby on Rails app and noticed that when I scroll back and forth between pages in my app on iPhone or iPad in Safari, the content of the previous page flashes for a moment before the target page is loaded.

The best way I can explain the problem is with a short 5-second video:

[Streamable video](http://streamable.com/tq4nz)

Other websites, including production sites build on Rails, do not seem to have this problem.

Why does it happen and how can I solve it?

Answer (score -1):

It's because of **turbolinks** that come shipped with Rails.

Here is a solution, assuming you never wanted to use turbolinks in the first place:

1. Remove the `gem 'turbolinks'` line from your Gemfile.
2. Remove the `//=require turbolinks` from your
   app/assets/javascripts/application.js.
3. Remove the two `"data-turbolinks-track" => true` hash key/value
   pairs from your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.